# How to debug this Install Pods error on an EAS build for React Native Application

Tags: ios, react-native, build, expo, cocoapods

So I have no problem building out to android, but the ios build is getting hung up at this step of the build process:

```
Using Expo modules
[Expo] Enabling modular headers for pod ExpoModulesCore
Auto-generating `.xcode.env.local` with $NODE_BINARY=/Users/expo/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.0/bin/node
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBCrashlytics: [RNFB] Crashlytics Configuration
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: 
[!] Invalid `RNSVG.podspec` file: undefined method `visionos' for #<Pod::Specification name="RNSVG">.
 #  from /Users/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/react-native-svg/RNSVG.podspec:18
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    s.tvos.exclude_files = '**/*.macos.{h,m,mm}'
 >    s.visionos.exclude_files = '**/*.macos.{h,m,mm}'
 #    s.osx.exclude_files = '**/*.ios.{h,m,mm}'
 #  -------------------------------------------
.
 #  from /Users/expo/workingdir/build/ios/Podfile:43
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    use_expo_modules!
 >    config = use_native_modules!
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------
Error: Unknown error. See logs of the Install pods build phase for more information.
```

I've tried running `eas build -p ios --clear-cache`, and have ensured to update to the latest version of cocoapods with `sudo gem install cocoapods`, with no success.